# Build war file from Vertx project using Maven

Tags: maven, tomcat, vert.x

I've created a **Vert.x** project referring [this](https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs). Also created a run configuration in eclipse referring [this](https://youtu.be/iyZwAzEVX-o). The project successfully run as an application project in Eclipse and http://localhost:8080 is accesible.

As per the document it uses `maven shade plugin` to build a `fat-jar` (*if I build it using Maven via terminal*), which I only copy pasted, not understood much.

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Launcher</Main-Class>
                <Main-Verticle>${main.verticle}</Main-Verticle>
              </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory</resource>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
          <artifactSet>
          </artifactSet>
          <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <mainClass>io.vertx.core.Launcher</mainClass>
      <arguments>
        <argument>run</argument>
        <argument>${main.verticle}</argument>
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Every examples says to create the `jar` file and run it on terminal. But I need to **deploy this project into a tomcat server**, as a WAR file. This server system is not accessible for me, so I must hand over the WAR to admin.
How can a WAR file be produced from this ? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

A *Vert.x* application, although may be embedded into existing applications, is meant to be executed on its own (which may help you avoid many issues including `ClassLoader` ones).

Following the mentioned [guideline](https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/), you should have created a *Web API* using *Vert.x* and which runs under the hood by an embedded server which prevents you from using *Tomcat* as a runtime container.